# array usage inside rails remove duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I've got this array coming back from a web scrape. Which looks like this:

```
[["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"]]
```

So what happens is that it duplicates? So i'm wanting to change the above array to this (it will be different everytime so it'd need to remove duplicates.):

```
[["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"],
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"],
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"],
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"],
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"]
```

Anything else that exists after this is a dupe.

What i'm needing is the fees and the price to be on a var so i can save it down to the database :)

Thanks
Sam

**extra**
Heres the raketask.

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"
namespace :task do
  task test: :environment do
    ticketmaster_url = "http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/derren-brown-miracle-glasgow-04-07-2016/event/370050789149169E?artistid=1408737&majorcatid=10002&minorcatid=53&tpab=-1"
     doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(ticketmaster_url))
     event_name = nil
     ticket_price = nil
     doc.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()").each do |text|
       if text.content =~ /more_options_on_polling/
         ticket_price = text.to_s.scan(/\"(formatted_(?:price|sum_fees))\":\"(.+?)\"/)
         byebug
       end
     end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add `uniq` method on array that you've got from web scrape, which will give you an `uniq` values from that array, and then you can easily iterate on that array to store values into database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like

```
[["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], 
["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"], 
["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"]].uniq
```

Then result is:

```
 [["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"], ["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"], ["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"], ["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"], ["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"], ["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand this?